# Python: while loop/ control statements not achieving desired result, how can i fix this?

Tags: loops, if-statement, for-loop, python-3.x, while-loop

```
cost = int(input("Enter the cost:\n"))
payment = int(input("Deposit a coin or note:\n"))

if payment >= cost:
    change = payment - cost
    print (change)

elif payment < cost:
    while payment < cost:
        payment = int(input("Deposit a coin or note:\n"))
        change = cost - payment
        print (change)
        break
```

I basically want the value of "change".

The above was wrong because it wasn't 'storing' the value of the first payment if it was less than cost, realized my bad mistake.

```
cost = int(input("Enter the cost:\n"))
payment = 0
while payment < cost:
    firstpayment = int(input("Deposit a coin or note:\n"))
    payment = payment + firstpayment
    if payment > cost:
        change = payment - cost
        print ("Your change is: $",change)
```

Comment: take out the `change` from the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop condition says:

```
while payment< cost:
```

So, the loop automatically exists when payment becomes more than cost. So an easier approach will be,

```
while payment<cost:
    #do something
change = payment-cost
```

Coz, when the loop ends, we know that payment should be >= cost...